# get {} is not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net

```
  public class Settings
    {
        public static readonly string fileName = "config.ini";
        private IConfigSource src
        {
            get
            {
                CreateIfNotExists();
                return new IniConfigSource(fileName);
            }
        }

       public void test1()
        {
            //var src = new IniConfigSource(fileName); ;
            src.Configs["DATA"].Set("baa", "haaaaee");
            src.Save();
        }

       public void test2()
        {
            var src2 = new IniConfigSource(fileName); ;
            src2.Configs["DATA"].Set("baa", "haaaaee");
            src2.Save();
        }

    public Stream CreateIfNotExists()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Stream file = File.Create(fileName);
            return file;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

why the `test2()` method works fine and `test1()` not works?

Comment: Why do you have the declaration of `src` commented out in test1?

Comment: What happens? Is there an Exception thrown?

Comment: We'd need more code to understand. The source of `src` and what it has to do with CreateIfNotExists, which looks like a memory leak.

Comment: No we don't. It's pretty obvious once you look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because your "src" property creates a new IniConfigSource every single time it's called. Your "test" is expecting it to be the same one across calls.

Store the result of your IniConfigSource in a private variable, and use that if it's set.

```
    private IConfigSource _src;
    private IConfigSource src
    {
        get
        {
            if( _src == null )
                _src = new IniConfigSource(fileName);
            return _src;
        }
    }
```

I'm not going to get into why CreateIfNotExists is there at all, considering the Stream returned is never used and discarded to the GC.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are working with two instances of src. Change your code to that:

```
public class Settings     
{ 
     public static readonly string fileName = "config.ini"; 
     private IConfigSource src;
     private IConfigSource Src
     {  
         get  
         { 
              CreateIfNotExists();  
              return src; 
         }  
     }    
     public void test1()   
     {
         //var src = new IniConfigSource(fileName); 
         Src.Configs["DATA"].Set("baa", "haaaaee");      
         Src.Save();     
     }      
     public void test2()  
     { 
         Src.Configs["DATA"].Set("baa", "haaaaee");
         Src.Save();         
     }    
     public Stream CreateIfNotExists()     
     { 
         if (!File.Exists(fileName))         
         {
              Stream file = File.Create(fileName);
              src = new IniConfigSource(fileName);
              return file;        
         } 
         src = null;
         return null;    
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`src` in `test1` and `test2` are two different instances of `IniConfigSource` (**no longer valid with your edit**).

The reason test1 fails is that a new instance is created on every line.

```
// src property creates new IniConfigSource and sets value appropriately
src.Configs["DATA"].Set("baa", "haaaaee"); 

// src property creates new IniConfigSource and essentially saves nothing
src.Save();
```

Comment: +1 because you are right and the downvoting of someone else was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateIfNotExists` creates an instance of `FileStream` and doesn't dispose it. This leads to the `FileStream` locking the file, and thus the subsequent opening of that file fails.

And the instance of `IniConfigSource` from the first test might keep the file open too, but I don't know that for sure, since you didn't post the relevant sourcecode.

Your lazy initialization pattern is also broken, returning a new instance of `IniConfigSource` on each access. If you want lazy initialization, why not just use the `Lazy<T>` class?

---

In addition to that bug, a getter with a side effect is *very* bad style.

Another (minor) issue is the race condition between the exists check, and the call the create. If the file gets deleted in between the code fails.

Comment: it is not my real code. in real code I close the file stream

Comment: @TheMask then post the real code or at least a representative subset of it. You need to dispose it before opening the file for the next time, so the first test probably blocks the second test.